# Get Windows Phone app information

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there a way to get info about particular app such as number of downloads, some kind of statistics etc., not being its owner. I am wondering whether exists any API to get information from Windows Phone Market? Thank you in advance. Last concern : is it enable to use another ad on windows phone than microsoft advertising? Will such app be approved on market?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such Api to Access these things.

Comment: What about other questions?

Comment: yes you can use other ads. There is no issue for Approval

Comment: Don't use AdMob(Google) generate so much crash and destroy your ranking in market !!!

Comment: @RichiR. What do you mean by Windows Phone Market here?

Comment: I came up with idea to create own advertisements system therefore I am curious how it works, any suggestions and councils would be highly appreciated.